# Karnaugh map & Quine McCluskey

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, simplify, karnaugh-map

I would like to know if the same answer should be obtained when simplifying an expression using a karnaugh map and the mccluskey method. I guess that it does but I would prefer to get a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer obtained from simplifying an expression using a Karnaugh map and the Quine-McCluskey method may not be the same, as the two methods have different strengths and weaknesses.

The Karnaugh map is a graphical method for simplifying Boolean expressions and is useful for identifying the minimum number of terms needed to represent an expression. It is well-suited for small to medium-sized expressions and can be easier to use than other methods.

The Quine-McCluskey method, on the other hand, is a tabular method for simplifying Boolean expressions and is useful for large expressions. It is more systematic and efficient than other methods, but can also be more complex to use.

In general, both methods are useful for simplifying Boolean expressions and can be used to obtain equivalent expressions. However, the answer obtained from each method will depend on the expression being simplified and the method used to simplify it.